# Create Classes at Compile time

Tags: java, spring

I always wonder about classes that are created at Compile time, like for example in Spring DATA, i could simply create interface like this

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

   List<User> findByLastname(String lastname);

  User findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);}
```

As I know Spring Data create classes with the appropriate implementation for this interface, is that right? and if right how does it do it? is there a specific API that is commonly used for creating classes that implement interfaces?

Comment: Spring Data does not generate classes at *compile time* - it creates proxy implementations of repository interfaces at *runtime*.